# MySQL calculation minute using TIMEDIFF()

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate total time a student is in class based from differences in timestamp times.

Here is the table which I am using...

```
CREATE TABLE Students(
  studentID varchar(255), 
  firstName varchar(255), 
  lastName varchar(255), 
  updated_at TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  total_time INTEGER DEFAULT NULL
);
```

ex.) student record at 9:39AM is updated to 9:40AM. The dif here is 1 min... so 1 gets added to the students total_time.

The sql statement I currently have is...

```
UPDATE Students SET total_time = TIMEDIFF(CURTIME(), updated_at);
```

However, TIMEDIFF returns a Time variable if I am correct... how can I turn that to minutes? ALSO... would this work even with the correct casting to minutes? Because of the "ON UPDATE" method used for the updated_at column, I would imagine the timestamp would just be updated, then the calculated difference would always be 0, since the two would be the same.

UPDATE: It is vital to mention these records will likely be updated more than once-per minute.

Comment: check for mysql `timestampdiff` function, you can get the difference in minutes,hours, seconds etc.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty that was a very good idea. I did not know of this mysql function... however it was returning some very large numbers. I will have to go back and check my implementation of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query
to get minutes use this:

> UPDATE Students SET total_time = TIMEDIFF(NOW(), updated_at)/60;

to get seconds use this:

```
UPDATE Students SET total_time = TIMEDIFF(NOW(), updated_at)/1;
```

Comment: This almost works, it wont work when the record is updated more than once a minute though... because then it will set total_time back to 0.

Comment: if you want it by second you can divide / 1 like this: 
UPDATE Students SET total_time = TIMEDIFF(NOW(), updated_at)/1;